# TeamCity - Pre-tested commits

Tags: java, teamcity

How does TeamCity verify if the code sent by the developer is a pre-tested commit?

Answer (score 3):

The pre-tested commit feature works through plugins that integrate with your IDE.

If you use Eclipse:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Eclipse+Plugin

If you use IntelliJ:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/IntelliJ+Platform+Plugin

I you use Visual Studio:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Visual+Studio+Plugin

The help documentation on that site should guide you through installing the plugin and setting up the pre-tested commits.  I haven't done it in a while, but as far as I remember it's a painless process.

Answer (score 0):

1. Developer sends the changes from his IDE (see [TeamCity documentation page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Pre-Tested+%28Delayed%29+Commit) for the list of supported IDEs and pipeline description. But please note the list is not full, there are plugins for another IDEs such as PyCharm).
2. TeamCity server receives it and applies patch to the existing code from repository and then builds the patched code.

Usually it makes sense when build and test process don't take a lot of time, so developer can receive results in a few seconds just to his IDE (I tried it with PyCharm and it was great - it notifies you in a few seconds about build results).

So there is no magic with this verification, it's pretty clear.